# Scene change detection

Tags: video-editor

What off the shelf (COTS or OpenSource) have scene change detection? I would really like one that is not a fixed algorithm, but can either use motion vectors, audio, or static analysis depending on our needs.

Is there something beyond what is already talked about in:
[Split one video file into small files made up of its scenes](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12634/split-one-video-file-into-small-files-made-up-of-its-scenes)

Or with the matlab tool:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/scene-change-detection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working with Magnum 3 (http://aescripts.com/magnum/) {a plugin in for After Effects} for a few days. It definitely meets my needs (at $39.99). Things I like:

1. You can set the threshold for scene detection
2. You can get a graph of the detection layer, where spikes show values on timeline for where detection is higher (set the threshold to include all the spikes you want)
3. Either splits the layer, or creates markers
4. You can export thumbnails for scene changes, and a text file for the "EDL" (actually, you have a template you can use to write out Text or CSV files in any format you want).

Answer (score 1):

Both Speedgrade and Davinci Resolve have scene change detection.

Davinci Resolve is also free. I am not sure however on how exactly it detects scenes changes.

Comment: I sorta like the flexibilty of the Magnum3 plug-in for After Effects, But I am not sure how to get the split scene back into Premiere (SpeedGrade puts out an EDL but Premiere does not understand EDLs that operate on one clip. http://aescripts.com/magnum/

Comment: I think that SpeedGrade and Premiere can talk via Dynamic Link while both are running. No need to mess with EDL files.

Comment: It can talk via dynamic link. But two issues. 1. MP4 files when linked to speed grade do not allow scene detect. So one still has to export as avi or QuickTime (full frame data) Issue 2: even if you dl-link an avi from premiere. The clips on the timeline do not show premiere.